# Warum wurde"abend" in "Dienstag abend" früher klein geschrieben?

Tags: history, reformed-orthography

Seit der Rechtschreibreform 1996 werden Fügungen aus Wochentag und Tageszeit zusammen geschrieben:

> Dienstag + Abend = Dienstagabend

Die Überlegung hinter dieser Regel scheint zu sein, dass die Tageszeit als Substantiv aufgefasst wird:

> Dienstagabend = der Abend des Dienstag

So führt auch die [Rechtschreibregel D69](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D69) aus:

> Die Bezeichnungen von Tageszeiten nach Adverbien wie gestern, heute, morgen werden als Substantive angesehen und großgeschrieben <§ 55 (6)>.
>
> Zum Beispiel
>
> vorgestern Nacht (vgl.: vorgestern in der Nacht)
>   gestern Abend (vgl.: gestern am Abend)

Die relative Zeitangabe *früh* dagegen wird in Deutschland (anders als in Österreich) als Adverb angesehen und in Fügungen mit Wochentagen klein geschrieben:

> Dienstag früh, heute früh (Österreich: heute Früh = heute + die Früh)

Diese heutigen Rechtschreibregeln scheinen einleuchtend, denn Angaben der Tageszeit wie *der Abend* und *der Morgen* empfinden wir als Substantive. Vor der Rechtschreibreform wurden Fügungen aus Wochentag und Tageszeit dagegen getrennt und die Tageszeit klein geschrieben:

> Dienstag + abend = Dienstag abend

Warum? Wurde damals *abend*, anders als heute, als Adverb aufgefasst? Wenn ja, wo findet sich dieses Adjektiv heute noch?

Comment: Vielleicht eine Analogiebildung auf das kleine _früh_? Als Österreicher erscheint mir zumindest schon dabei die Kleinschreibung weniger logisch. Aber bei uns ist _in der Früh_ ugs. auch bei Weitem gebräuchlicher als _am Morgen_.

Comment: Was lässt dich annehmen dass das frühere 'abend' und das heutige 'abends' nicht äquivalent sind? 'Dienstag abends' geht doch heute immer noch, oder?

Comment: @bukwyrm Wie kommst du darauf, dass *abend* == *abends* sein könnte?!? Zur Schreibung vor der Rechtschreibreform s. https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/gestern_abend.shtml

Comment: Das kleingeschriebene *früh* als Adjektiv aufzufassen macht keinen Sinn, allenfals wird es als *Adverb* aufgefasst, wie in der zitierten Rechtschreibregel.

Comment: "Morgen früh" ist eindeutig ein Adverb, siehe die Beispiele hier: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/frueh_morgens_Morgen_Fruehe

Comment: @RHa Da hast du wohl recht.

Comment: @phipsgabler: *»in der Früh«* ist in Österreich nicht umgangssprachlich! Das ist bestes österreichisches Standarddeutsch. Das darf man in Schulaufsätze schreiben, das [drucken Zeitschriften](https://www.woman.at/a/kaffee-frueh-zeitpunkt-wacher) und das sagen Politiker (S. Kurz im Jänner 2019: »Ich glaube nicht, dass es eine gute Entwicklung ist, wenn immer weniger Menschen **in der Früh** aufstehen, ...«) Wir Österreicher sollten nicht immer so tun, als wäre unser Standard irgendwie minderwertiger nur weil es mehr Manschen in einem anderen Land gibt, die einen anderen Standard verwenden. ...

Comment: ... Deutsch ist ja auch ganz allgemein nicht schlechter als z.B. Spanisch, nur weil mehr Menschen Spanisch sprechen als Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wenn ich den Kommentar von phipsgabler richtig verstehe, meinte er nicht, dass *in der Früh* (nur) umgangssprachlich sei, sondern dass es in der Umangssprache gebräuchlicher sei als *am Morgen*. Und eine Abwertung des Österreichischen oder der deutschen Sprache kann ich in seinem Kommentar auch nicht erkennen.

Comment: https://www.bag.ch/brunner-medien-ag/aktuelles/blog/20-jahre-neue-rechtschreibungwir-sind-auf-dem-richtigen-weg-677 schreibt "Die Befürworter der Kleinschreibung argumentierten, «abend» sei adverbial zu verstehen, leite sich von «abends» ab"

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht sind die Wörter *»früh«* und *»Früh«* der Schlüssel zur Antwort:

Wiktionary kennt das kleingeschriebene Wort *»früh«* als [Adjektiv](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fr%C3%BCh#Adjektiv) (*»Ich war zu **früh** dort.«*) und als [Adverb](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fr%C3%BCh#Adverb) (*»Ich war Dienstag **früh** dort.«*).

Daneben gibt es auch das großgeschriebene [Substantiv](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fr%C3%BCh) *»die Früh«,* das eigentlich nur in der Wortkombination *»in der Früh«* verwendet wird, und das auch nur in Österreich und dem Südosten Bayerns, wie das folgende Bild zeigt:

[image: Dienstag Morgen/Früh]
<sup>Quelle: [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r12-f4b/)</sup>

Dort sieht man auch sehr schön, dass es zwischen *»Dienstag Morgen«* und *»Dienstag früh/Früh«* nicht, wie sonst so häufig zu sehen ist (z.B. bei Junge/Bub) eine Nord-Süd-Teilung des deutschen Sprachraums gibt, sondern eine Ost-West-Teilung.

Dass in dem Bild das Wort *»Früh«* in *»Dienstag Früh«* großgeschrieben ist, liegt daran, dass der Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache ein Projekt der Universität Salzburg ist, und dass daher Österreichisches Deutsch die Arbeitssprache ist, und in Österreich die großgeschriebene Variante von *»Früh«* die Norm und die kleingeschriebene Version die erlaubte Ausnahme ist.

---

##### Gegenwörter

Das Gegenwort zum Substantiv *»die Früh«* ist *»der Abend«.* Aber während Ereignisse **in** (nicht *an*) der Früh stattfinden, ist es eher selten, dass etwas *»**in** dem (=im) Abend«* stattfindet, sondern viel häufiger *»**an** dem (=am) Abend«*. (Aber: *»Sie stand schon **im Abend** ihres Lebens, als sie Bücher zu schreiben begann.«*)

> Ich habe sie am Dienstag **in der Früh** gesehen.
> Ich habe sie am Dienstag **am Abend** gesehen.

Das Gegenwort zum Adjektiv ist *»spät«*:

> Ich war zu **früh** dort.
> Ich war zu **spät** dort.

Wenn es zum Adjektiv und zum Substantiv Gegenwörter gibt, wäre dann nicht auch ein Gegenwort zum Adverb denkbar? Etwa so?

> Ich war Dienstag **früh** dort.
> Ich war Dienstag **abend** dort.

Ich vermute, dass das genau die Überlegung war, warum man zwischen 1901 und 1996 das Wort *»abend«* in Fügungen wie *»Dienstag abend«* kleingeschrieben hat, wie folgendes Ngram zeigt. (Den Teil von 2005 bis heute habe ich absichtlich weggelassen, weil nach 2005 die Häufigkeit von »heute Abend« drastisch zunahm und dadurch die Kurven vor 2005 zu stark nach unten gedrückt worden wären.)

[image: Google Ngram: heute abend, heute Abend]
Quelle: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heute%20abend%2Cheute%20Abend&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheute%20abend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheute%20Abend%3B%2Cc0)

---

Gegenwärtig wird das Wort *»Abend«* auch in *»Dienstag Abend«* nicht mehr als syntaktisch gleichwertig mit *»Dienstag früh«* angesehen, weswegen man es heutzutage immer großschreibt.

---

##### Zu *früh/Früh* in Österreich:

Es ist richtig, dass in Österreich die Formen *»heute Früh«, »morgen Früh«* usw. nicht nur erlaubt sind, sondern sogar bevorzugt verwendet werden, aber ebenso sind die Formen *»heute früh«, »morgen früh«* usw. in Österreich erlaubt.

Allerdings ist die in Österreich bei weitem vorherrschende Form diese: *»heute in der Früh«, »morgen in der Früh«* usw. Das Substantiv *»die Früh«* (übrigens ohne *e* am Ende) wird in Österreich wesentlich häufiger verwendet als *»der Morgen«.*

| In Ö bevorzugt | in Ö auch möglich | in Ö sehr selten |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gestern in der Früh | gestern Früh/früh | gestern Morgen, gestern am Morgen |
| heute in der Früh | heute Früh/früh | heute Morgen, gestern am Morgen |
| morgen in der Früh | morgen Früh/früh | morgen am Morgen |

(Die Kombination *»morgen Morgen«* ist überall unüblich)